# lemma for vector function mean value thorem

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $F$ be a differentiable function , $F:D\rightarrow R$, $D$ open in $R^n$ and $[\underline{a},\underline{b}]\subset D$. Given that ${\lVert \mathbf{df(\underline{u})} \rVert}$  is bounded  above by $M$ Then $  f(\underline{a})-f(\underline{b})\ge M \lVert \mathbf{\underline{a}-\underline{b}} \rVert$

I do not understand why we cannot assume that the set of differentials is bounded above. We could consider the associated matrix, as we are working on $R^n$ and this should be bounded.

Comment: I think you need to edit your typesetting.

Comment: If $F$ is not *continuously* differentiable then $||df(u)||$ may be unbounded even on (closed) segment. Take $F=x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x^2}$.